# Insert rendered view after base element

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

So I have a compositeView. CompositeView is an "ul" element with base first "li" element and a collection of another "li" elements. My objective is to insert each rendered child collection of elements after base "li" element.

My views code

```
var
_NavItem = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    tagName: 'li',
    template: function (serialized_model) {

        return _.template('<a href="/"><span class="<%= name %>"><%= name %></span></a>')(serialized_model);
    }   
});

var
_NavComposite = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

    tagName: 'li',
    className: 'header',
    childView: _NavItem,
    initialize: function () {

        this.collection = new Backbone.Collection(this.model.attributes.items);
    },
    template: function (serialized_model) {

        return _.template('<%= name %>')(serialized_model);
    },
    attachHtml: function(collectionView, childView){

        collectionView.$el.append(childView.el);
    }
});

var
_NavigationView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({

    tagName: 'ul',
    childView: _NavComposite
});
```

and in fact this code will render structure

```
ul
    li (base0) /li
    li /li (li of collection)
    li /li (li of collection)
    ...
    li (base1) /li
    li /li (li of collection)
    li /li (li of collection)
    ...
    li (base2) /li
    li /li (li of collection)
    li /li (li of collection)
    ...
/ul
```

but when I start this nothing happend. 
If I change code to

```
attachHtml: function(compositeView, childView){

    compositeView.$el.append(childView.el);
}
```

it works fine, but this render another structure, that I want

```
ul
    li (base0)
        li /li (li of collection)
        li /li (li of collection)
        ...
        li /li (li of collection)
    /li
    li (base1)
        li /li (li of collection)
        li /li (li of collection)
        ...
        li /li (li of collection)
    /li
    ...
/ul
```

Structure of data

```
[0: { id: 1, name: 'Base li name 1', items: [ 
    0: {id: 2, name: 'Li child 1'},
    1: {id: 3, name: 'Li child 2'}
]}, 
1: { id: 4, name: 'Base li name 2', items: [ 
    0: {id: 5, name: 'Li child 3'},
    1: {id: 6, name: 'Li child 4'}
]}
...
]
```

Comment: `compositeView.$el.append(childView.el);` should give you the structure you asked for in question. What structure do you mean when you say  *"but I want to see another structure"*..?

Comment: @TJ I update my question to set it more clear

Comment: Can you post the entire CollectionView?

Comment: @seebiscuit No, I want to render one list, not a tree

Comment: How do you determine where a base li will go between the collection models?

Comment: @seebiscuit Update post again in the end, show the structure for Views.

Comment: See my update. Would you like to see how I would create that structure? You can always manage the look using css.

Comment: @seebiscuit thank you very much for your help! I understand how to apply your answear. One more question, why .after did not works?

Comment: Because you're appending below the CompositeView wrapper. Marionette only attaches the view wrapper to the view, not something you attached **outside** of it. So these hanging items, outside of the view wrapper never get attached.

Comment: @seebiscuit thanks again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### UPDATE TO CHANGED QUESTION:

Because of the view wrappers generated by Backbone.View, there is no way to get exactly the structure you want.You could at best have multiple li's each with li (base) and sibling li (collection) items, but they would exist in a second level list. Like this,

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <ul>
         <li>
            composite0.model.name
         </li>
         <li>
            childView0.model.name
         </li>
           .
           .
           .
         <li>
            childViewN.model.name
         </li>
     </ul>    
  </li>
    .
    .
    .
  <li>
      <ul>
         <li>
            compositeN.model.name
         </li>
         <li>
            childView0.model.name
         </li>
           .
           .
           .
         <li>
            childViewN.model.name
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

---

I think all you really need is one CompositeView, and you can leverage the CompositeView template to get the effect you're looking for:

```
var _NavItem = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    template: function (serialized_model) {

        return _.template('<a href="/"><span class="<%= name %>"><%= name %></span></a>')(serialized_model);
    }   
});

var _NavBaseListView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

        tagName: 'ul',
        className: 'header',
        childView: _NavItem,
        template: function (serialized_model) {
            return _.template('<li><%= name %></li>')(serialized_model);
        },
        attachHtml: function(collectionView, childView){        
            collectionView.$el.append(childView.el);
        }
});
```

## How it works

The template on the CompositeView will return

```
<li>
   composite.model.name
</li>
```

and when `attachHtml` in the CompositeView is invoked, the `childView`, which is another `<li>` will simply be appended below the base `<li>` described in the CompositeView template. (BTW, you don't have to override `attachHtml` at all, since `collectionView.$el.append` is the default behavior [well sort of, because it buffers the children and then appends the group, but it's the same result]).

At the end you'll end up with

```
<ul>
   <li>
      composite.model.name
   </li>
   <li>
      childView0.model.name
   </li>
     .
     .
     .
   <li>
      childViewN.model.name
   </li>
</ul>
```

In fact this is one of the reasons CompositeView was built in the first place, see [Composite Views: Tree Structures, Tables, And More](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/05/composite-views-tree-structures-tables-and-more/), see the **Grid Views** part.

Comment: Of course you are right, thanks for your answear. But if base "li" more then 1, it will not work.

Comment: That is true, but then, in your question you didn't specify that you needed more than one base li. That's one of the big shortcomings I found with Marionette--you can't have more than one collection in a collection view...

Comment: It is my mistake and I'am so sorry. I update my post again, hope this addition will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the heart of the problem is that the structure you are proposing is not valid HTML. From MDN:

> The HTML `<li>` element (or HTML List Item Element) is used to represent an item in a list. It must be contained in a parent element: an ordered list (`<ol>`), an unordered list (`<ul>`), or a menu (`<menu>`). In menus and unordered lists, list items are usually displayed using bullet points. In ordered lists, they are usually displayed with an ascending counter on the left, such as a number or letter.

When you nest `<li>` elements the proper structure is to have each new level of the list to be wrapped in a `<ul>`.

Either you should be using `div`s for your structure or wrap nested `<li>`s in a `<ul>`.

If you choose to change your structure than it would be much easier for Marionette to accommodate that.

Comment: Of course in the end of view render, html structure must be valid and if .after function worked we can see it. But @seebiscuit was right when talk "Marionette only attaches the view wrapper to the view". That is why I will use another data or html structure.